# How to create dynamic div in javascript without using jquery?

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to make dynamic division on button click on my web page please tell me easiest solution, I am new to JavaScript.

Comment: Have a look at http://www.w3.org/wiki/Creating_and_modifying_HTML, http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-dom-intro/ and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/learn/javascript in general.

Comment: @Android Programmer - Welcome to SO. Please do look around once to check if a similar question has been asked and answered elsewhere. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this will help

```
function divcreate() {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.setAttribute("id", "mydiv");
    div.className = "mdiv";
    div.style.display = "none";
    document.body.appendChild(div);
}
```

Comment: Why do you use `div.setAttribute('id',...)` and not `div.id = ...;`? And why do you have so much space on the left side of your code?

Comment: is it ok now  Felix Kling ;)

Answer (score 2):

To create an element, use the [`createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createElement) method

```
var mydiv = document.createElement('div');
//mydiv is a variable containing a newly created div
```

Comment: and document.body.appendChild(mydiv)

Comment: @GrzegorzKaczan the OP only mentioned *creating* one

Answer (score 0):

```
<button onclick="createDiv()">Click Me</button>

function createDiv(){
   var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

//create a div like below

```
var div=document.createElement("div");
var node=document.createTextNode("This is new.");
div.appendChild(node);
```

Then append the above div to which you want it to be child

```
var element=document.getElementById("some_parent_tag");
element.appendChild(div);
```